# Standing sound wave tube

Tags: waves, acoustics, propulsion

If there was a standing sound wave tube and a flammable gas was introduced then ignited, would the combustion be more forceful and more efficient since its following a standing wave, than just a gas ignited within a tube?

Comment: What does "forceful" and "efficient" mean?

Comment: exertion of more force = forceful

Comment: efficient - the gas is burning at a higher capacity due to the standing wave

Comment: Although I appreciate accepting the answer, I recommend leaving it unaccepted for awhile. My answer isn't particularly great, just enough to get somebody started, and somebody may want to come along and give a really awesome answer. But they're less likely to do that if my answer is already accepted. So just wait a little while before clicking the check mark and you might get better answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your terms are not precise, I have a feeling that what you are describing is a [Rubens' Tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubens%27_tube).

Yes, the combustion reflects the standing wave as shown below (from Wikipedia):

[image: From Wikipedia]

Recall that sound is made up of pressure waves and so a standing sound wave means there is larger pressure at some points and lower pressure at others. At the high pressure points, the fuel is pushed out through the opening faster resulting in a taller flame. Also, because the density is increased, more fuel comes out and combustion in enhanced. The opposite is true at the lower pressure regions.

Comment: If the wave pattern were centered in the tube, using 3 equal tones set apart at 60 degrees, would this equalize the pressure at both ends of the tube assuming both ends were open.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'high pressure' and 'lower pressure' regions in terms of pressure/displacement nodes/antinodes? As far as I know, nodes are the regions where the pressure is constant at all times and equal to the ambient pressure. Pressure oscillates at antinodes about the mean. I think there's no particular region which we could classify as high/low pressure.

Comment: @GuruVishnu Your understanding of nodes and antinodes is correct. But in a standing wave, the incident and reflected waves interfere in such a way that it looks like nothing is moving, resulting in higher and lower pressures at the antinodes.